# Como ejecutar un programa de consola .out en ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Quiero ejecutar mi programa que hice en c++ es de consola y el compilador me da un archivo con extensión .out, cuando quiero abrirlo me sale un mensaje de que no hay un programa para abrirlo

Comment: podrias revisar esto: https://rupinderjeetkaur.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/run-a-cc-program-on-terminal-using-gcc-compiler/

Comment: `chmod a+x a.out` `./a.out`